# Tags in Specflow

Tags: c#, jenkins, tags, specflow

I'm currently working on a project where we use Specflow (C#) to implement BDD acceptance tests. The scenarios are common for 4 different regions. I use tags to categorize the region.

For example -

@US @UK @INDIA @SRILANKA
Scenario: Login with valid credentials
Given as a user I launch ABC application
When I login with valid credentials
Then I should be logged in successfully

@INDIA @SRILANKA
Scenario: Login with invalid credentials
Given as a user I launch ABC application
When I login with invalid credentials
Then I should not be logged in successfully

@US @UK
Scenario: Login with no credentials
Given as a user I launch ABC application
When I login with no credentials
Then I should not be logged in successfully

The scenatio defined above should be used for all 4 regions. I'm aware that I can categorize in Test Explorer in Visual Studio. But the challenge I have is, I have 4 Jenkins jobs created for each region called

1. Jenkins_Job_US
2. Jenkins_Job_UK
3. Jenkins_Job_INDIA
4. Jenkins_Job_SRILANKA

I need to execute scenarios according to the tag names from Jenkins.

Can anyone help me please.

Comment: Which test runner are you using? NUnit, XUnit, MsTest, SpecFlow+ Runner?

Comment: Apols for the delay @Abdres Willich... Im using NUnit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Console-Command-Line
https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Test-Selection-Language

In your situation:

nunit3-console mytest.dll --where "cat == SRILANKA"